# Your function app is not optimized for best cold-start because the site placeholder id is: Disabled:PCerts

Tags: azure-functions

In several of our Azure Function apps, we have the following under "Availability risk alerts":

> Your function app is not optimized for best cold-start because the site placeholder id is: Disabled:PCerts.
>
> We detect that the site placeholder id is: Disabled:PCerts. This could impact the function app’s performance and increase cold-start.

There's no links in the warning and neither Google nor Bing turn up anything helpful. What do I need to fix that's triggering this warning?

App Service Plan: ([Gist of ARM template](https://gist.github.com/af4jm/51dad8189d909a9abc538eb06401180c))

```json
"sku": {
    "name": "Y1",
    "tier": "Dynamic",
    "size": "Y1",
    "family": "Y",
    "capacity": 0
}
```

Comment: In Which Hosting Plan, you deployed the function app?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT edited to add the App Service Plan sku... if that's not what you meant by hosting plan, please clue me in... thx!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the function app is in consumption plan and [cold starts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/) could occur in this SKU as there is no ["always on"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan#always-on) feature. Please note that, when there is no incoming traffic/load on the function app, the function will only have placeholder instances. This is just a warning message and only way I can think of to avoid this warning is to move to premium or dedicated app service plan.